# Using schema validation: custom date type and datepicker control

Tags: datepicker, orbeon, xforms, xmlschema

I'm using Orbeon 2019.2 CE on Tomcat 8, using plain XForms.

I have xml schema for xml docs that will completed by several people, so I need to be conscious of whether the document will be valid *before* it is complete. For date fields, I understand there are three main ways of creating a "date or blank" type:

- using `xsi:nil`
- making a union type of an xs:date and empty string
- using a list type containing an xs:date that can have a length of 0 or 1.

I've tried the 2nd and third way, this works as expected for xml validation, but in XForms where I have specified the schema in the model, the datepicker control doesn't seem to work with the custom type. I would like to use schema validation **and** have an empty date field be valid. (I know about `xf:date` allowing no value vs. `xs:date` that doesn't). There is no problem when **not** using schema validation, but I really would like to be able to use it as it "externalizes" validation rules to some extent. I am also using the form runner [error summary component](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/error-summary).  When using validation (`<model schema='uri_to_schema'>`), and a "date or nothing" type in the schema (as described above) I see this:

- If date field binding does not specify `xs:date` or `xf:date`, no
  datepicker appears with the `xf:input` field. Typing a date with the
  format "2000-01-01" is valid, a blank field is valid, and anything
  else gets flagged as invalid (both by the error component and
  external validation). I also noticed that Orbeon is aware that is a
  custom type, as the class `xforms-type-custom-date-or-nothing`
  appears in the HTML ("date-or-nothing" is the name of the type).
- If I put `type='xs:date'` in the binding for the date field, no
  datepicker appears, and the input is flagged as invalid (until you
  enter a date value)
- If I put `type='xf:date'` in the binding, the field initially
  presents without the datepicker. If I put a valid date (format:
  yyyy-mm-dd), it's not flagged.  If I put anything else (like 'abc'),
  it will be flagged by the error component, then the datepicker will
  appear, but it will be **empty**. However, in FormInspector, the
  field still has the invalid value, and the document (through external
  validation)  is invalid. If I subsequently select a valid date from
  the datepicker, the flagged error goes away, but the field is blank
  again.
- If I change the schema to use `xs:date` instead of the custom type
  ("date-or-nothing"), all is well using schema validation, except the
  document is invalid until it has a date value.
- I have the schema instance referenced in the xform. I did try referencing the actual type from the schema by including the namespace of the schema in the xform, and then putting `type='mydoc:date-or-nothing'`, but I have not been able to get this to work.
- If I remove the schema from the model and use `xf:date` in the binding, all is well but now I don't have schema validation.

Does anyone have an option where I could use the custom type ***and*** have the datepicker appear? I don't see much documentation on using XML schema with xforms, so I'm guessing this might be an "edge case" that's not supported. Is there a way to "force" Orbeon to render a datepicker? (I looked to see if I could specify the "form-runner" component there, but the documentation only mentions other date control types). In searching, I thought I saw that the xforms specification allows an "appearance='date'" attribute on the "xf:input", but this is probably wrong as I could find no other mention of this.

It would be pretty disappointing if I had to ditch schema-based validation for any document that has a date field. In some cases, I could "get away" with making the date field mandatory for the first contributor of the document, but having the option would be much better. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Hi Francis, I'd suggest we take the items you mentioned in your question one-by-one, starting with your second bullet point: "If I put `type='xs:date'` in the binding for the date field, no datepicker appears, and the input is flagged as invalid (until you enter a date value)". Could you create the simplest standalone example that reproduces this, put on on Pastebin or similar, and link to it in a comment? -Alex

Comment: Hi Francis, just checking: is this still an issue for you? If so, is there a chance you would be able to create an example we can use to reproduce the problem? -Alex

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply.  I will try to prepare something minimal that reproduces the problem, it's just the matter of having the time. In the past I tried to get such things to "fit" in the application I'm working on, but maybe I should just try to run it from the Orbeon application. Any suggestions on the simplest way to create a test xform?

Comment: Hi Francis, I know the feeling ;), no rush on my side. About the date validation, in most cases, schemas are not used for this; in Form Builder you just add a date field, and Orbeon Forms validates the value as a date, without the need for a schema. Would this be good enough in your case? Or you maybe had some other reason for wanting to use a schema? -Alex

Comment: We are doing xforms "by hand", and we keep a schema "library" that includes some schema common to all documents. Using schema reduces the amount of "manual" validation needed in the xforms. Orbeon is getting the schema from a jar file in it's lib folder. The "date or nothing" type validates correctly, but the date picker can't be invoked. Is there a way to"force" Orbeon to use it?

Comment: Hi Francis, go it about the XForms being written "by hand"; how is your XForms using it though? Would you be able to share with me a minimal example that I can run to reproduce the problem? -Alex